# Call function with UI buttons instead of using keyboard buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my **2D Unity game** i can control my character with **arrow keys** and the **space bar**. Because I want it to be playable on **android phones**, i would like to use **UI buttons** instead.

I have already created **3 UI buttons**:

- ***Move right***;
- ***Move left***;
- ***Jump***.

I would like to make so that these three buttons would be able to do the same job as the keys do with the code i have now.

This is my ***Move2D*** script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Jump();
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) 
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: (In this script there are some function calls to another one called ***Grounded*** that check if the character is touching the floor).

-

Any information or advice is really appreciated.

Comment: sooo ? ... what have you tried so far? `Jump` should be pretty obvious ... and for `movement` you will need a method with a simple float parameter and in the button set it to either `1` or `-1` ... where is the problem?

Comment: Retrofitting touch controls is not a trvial thing. For most games, it is simply not a good input method. The game must be designed for it. Usually you design with the worst input method in mind, then expaned it for the cases where you can use more advanced ones like keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have read the docs and know how to reference and configure UI.Button in general (otherwise watch the [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button)) you could do it like

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // this one you simply reference to a normal button
    // or you could also use a continues button to auto jump see below
    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded) 
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private float movement;

    // this you reference on the left and right button
    public void Move(float value)
    {
        movement = value;
    }

    // AND AGAIN
    // you should always use MovePosition for RIGIDBODIES as I already told you last time

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + Vector2.right * movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Btw: In a 2D game you shouldn't use `Vector3` but `Vector2` for movement etc.

This one goes to your Buttons so you can extend them with a `whilePressed` callback:

```
public class ContinuesButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent whilePressed;

    private bool isHover;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WhilePressed());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressed()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            whilePressed?.Invoke();
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Put this on your left and right button and reference the `Move` method. To the one button pass e.g. `-1` to the other button `1` - all via the Inspector.

*More about the `IPointerXYHandler` can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.html)*

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no waranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thank you very much. How can i make so that it makes the character keep moving as long as the button is pressed?